# Showing GUI Texture only when button is held down?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

This script controls the cameras FOV when `"Fire2"` is pressed as well as displaying a GUI texture. However, once the user presses the button once, the texture displays and does not disappear until the button is pressed again - I want it to only show when the button is held down? This script is attached to a prefab which is a child object of the player prefab. I have tried to just use `GetButton` but seeing as `OnGUI()` is called every frame as well as the `Update()` function it just made the texture flicker.

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
public class awpScopeIn : MonoBehaviour {
 
    public Texture scopeGUI;
    private bool _isScoped = false;
    public Color color = Color.black;
    private Camera cam;
    public GameObject awp_graphics;
 
    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponentInParent( typeof(Camera) ) as Camera;
        cam.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;
        cam.fieldOfView = 70f;
    }
   
    void OnGUI()
    {
        float width = 600;
        float height = 600;
       
        if (_isScoped) {
            GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect ((Screen.width / 2) - (width/2), (Screen.height / 2) - (height/2), width, height), scopeGUI);  
        }
    }
   
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
        {
            _isScoped = !_isScoped;
            cam.backgroundColor = color;
            cam.fieldOfView = 45f;
            awp_graphics.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire2"))
        {
            cam.fieldOfView = 70f;
            awp_graphics.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  just changing the value when the button is pressed but you have to update the flag for showing texture when the button is released. So your Update method should be:

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
    {
        _isScoped = !_isScoped;
        cam.backgroundColor = color;
        cam.fieldOfView = 45f;
        awp_graphics.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire2"))
    {
        cam.fieldOfView = 70f;
        awp_graphics.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _isScoped = false;
    }
```